# Is there a way to restart an Exasol database instance automatically

Tags: exasolution, exasol

For reasons outlined here:  https://community.exasol.com/t5/discussion-forum/performance-on-premise-dropping/td-p/9029 we need to restart a database regularly (at least until al  issues are resolved, and this can take some time). So the question arises: Can this be done on a regular bases without human interaction?

LUA is not a solution, but perhaps a cron job is possible, but we need OS access for that, which we do not have.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `xmlrpc` API: https://github.com/exasol/exaoperation-xmlrpc/blob/master/EXAoperation_XMLRPC.md#method-restartdatabase

Here is a nice example with explanations: https://community.exasol.com/t5/environment-management/starting-and-stopping-clusters-using-xml-rpc/ta-p/1579

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible using the `shudownDatabase()` and `startDatabase()` methods from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/exasol/exaoperation-xmlrpc). You might need to use `stateDatabase()` in between to determine when the database is actually stopped before you try to start it again.